# Value of handles.axes in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

What value will get stored in `handles.axes` if image is present and if the image is not present?
I want check the condition whether image is present or not, and i implemented this

```
if handles.axes1==0
msgbox('Please insert image. . .', 'Error. . .');
end
```

but this is not working, please suggest me the best way of doing this.

Comment: How do you generate `handles.axes1` in the first place?

Comment: `axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(fname);`

Comment: There is a difference between [axes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html) graphic object and [image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html) object. Also use `ishghandle` to test if the handle is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your axes handle will not be modified by the call to `imshow` - this plots an image on an axes, but does nothing to the axes' handle. You can check if anything has been drawn in the axes with:

```
cs = get(handles.axes1, 'Children');
if isempty(cs)
    % Nothing in axes
else
    % Something has been drawn in the axes

    if any(strcmp(get(cs, 'Type'), 'image'))
        % An image has been drawn in the axes
    end
end
```

You could also use `findobj` to the same effect,

```
hasImage = ~isempty(findobj('Type', 'image', 'Parent', handles.axes1));
```